# Dapr Secret Store load Key Vault Certificate

Tags: .net, azure, docker-compose, dapr

I am having errors on the container app using Docker Compose to load the Dapr Secret Store with azure Key Vault , it cannot load the certificate file.

this is the Dapr documentation

[Dapr Link](https://docs.dapr.io/reference/components-reference/supported-secret-stores/azure-keyvault/)

[image]

my Yaml file

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: coresecretstore

spec:
  type: secretstores.azure.keyvault
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: vaultName
    value: srmdev-container-core
  - name: azureTenantId
    value: ******
  - name: azureClientId
    value : *******
  - name: azureCertificateFile
    value: \srmdev-container-core-SRMDEVContainerKeyVaultAccess-20240209.pfx
```

I get this error on the container log

```
time="2024-02-09T15:31:44.261183439Z" level=error msg="Error getting secret: ChainedTokenCredential: failed to acquire a token.\nAttempted credentials:\n\tmanaged identity\n\tAzureCLICredential: fork/exec /bin/sh: no such file or directory" app_id=project-reporting-service instance=e58b18eceeb3 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.12.0
```

the secretstore.yaml works fine if I add the azureClientSecret .

the certificate is located on the same folder as the yaml.

this is the folder structure

[image]

I have tried all different combination on the file path nothing works .
Any Ideas ?

Thanks